# how can i make a mask in Android to specify what i want to be clickable or not without touching the below or above objects?

Tags: android, imageview, mask, area, hit

[take a look here](http://imgh.us/1_2789.png)

as you can sea, there is 3 images have been designed and sliced by Photoshop, the white color of the human body ( 1 ) will be my absolute layout background, the others (2 and 3) should be over ( 1 )

when i import them ( 2 and 3 ) to Eclipse, Eclipse does not consider them as curved images, he just deal with them as rectangle objects, so if i use onTouch or onClick, there will be an errors because there will be shared area can be touch by the user:

how can i make a mask to specify what i want to be clickable or not without touching the below or above objects ?

[the final result should be like this](http://imgh.us/2_567.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write you own hit detection. The idea is simple:

- override onTouchEvent
- get the clicked pixel from the image
- if it's transparent, return false
- if not, call super.onTouchEvent